# Center div dynamically

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I need to make a website and there is a button which is in the middle horizontally. I can use left 50% or margin-left but when I minimize the window - it isn't in the middle. How do I set the div to be exactly in the middle also when you minimize the window of the browser?

Edit: fixed it by doing as Trix said and adding

```
.center-div{
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `div` has a `width` value, you may use:

**CSS**

```
.center-div{
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But, if not, you may add `text-align: center` to its parent and `display: inline-block;` to the centering `div` itself:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="center-div">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    text-align: center;
}
.parent .center-div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me a lot.